# CMS or html to build an e-commerce site in 30 days?

Tags: wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a c/c++ developer and i need to create an e-commerce site for someone in 30 days. I've done a bit of html and css recently (nothing extensive though) and I want to know whether to use a WordPress or html+bootstrap

Comment: There are plenty of open source eCommerce platform available. Download one and deploy it.. thats the easiest solution.\

Comment: With the described experience and from the form of the question, I think I can safely advise that you can't code an e-commerce site in 30 days. +1 to the above comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I think you all just made my job a whole lot easier. Will look into these platforms today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following CMSs.

1. WordPress (Woocommerce)
2. OpenCart

My vote goes for OpenCart as it's easy to learn, properly manged and designed only for eCommerce based websites.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the size and complexity of what you and the client are trying to achieve to start with.

Looking at your above comment though, I would suggest looking at building it around the Woo Commerce plugin for WordPress. You can use their free starter theme (storefront) or purchase a pre built one that you could customise further https://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/ through a child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

This way you have a pre built robust backend, theme, support and expendable features through plugins if needed. There are lot's of theme markets as well and ones which are likely built around Bootstrap (if that's what you're comfortable with), so if you have a good development area setup already, you could have the majority of the site setup locally in just a day or two.

If there's only a few products though you could always just slap some PayPal buttons on if you don't think you would be comfortable with the above.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to create just a eCommerce portal you should go with open cart. It is more easy and lot of theme available but if you want more features and future enhancement with some application you should go with magneto.

Note: Your site completion is depends on your requirement and you I am not sure about days.

[opencart](http://www.opencart.com/)
[magento](https://magento.com/)